# Isolate nested sass map into new map

Tags: sass, susy, sass-maps

How can I isolate nested sass map into a new map? For example I have sass map like this:

```
$susy-setting: (
  s: (
    'columns': 4,
    'gutters': 30px,
  ),

  m: (
    'columns': 8,
    'gutters': 30px,
  ),

  l: (
    'columns': 12,
    'gutters': 30px,
  )
);
```

Then I need to isolate each map inside after the loop, because my other mixin need map for its parameter.

```
@each $setting in $susy-setting{
    @include susy-settings-block($setting) { // This mixin need map
        @for $i from 1 through map-get($setting, 'columns') {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your primary question, you'll need to get both the key and value in your loop: `@each $size, $setting in $susy-setting`. The `$size` variable will store the key (e.g. `s`, `m`, `l`) while the `$setting` variable stores the map value assigned to that key.

EDIT: I saw your comment on my gist, which provides a bit more context. Try this:

```
@mixin susy-settings-block(
  $name, 
  $config: $susy-settings
) {
  // store the old settings
  $global: $susy;

  // Get the new settings by name
  $new: map-get($config, $name);

  // apply the new settings
  $susy: map-merge($susy, $new) !global;

  // allow nested styles, using new settings
  @content;

  // return to the initial settings
  $susy: $global !global;
}
```

Comment: Finally you are here Miriam :).
I think we have to move to gist, because my code still doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: Seems like I'm not getting notifications from Gist. Can you post the link here?

Comment: Sure. Here is the link https://gist.github.com/mirisuzanne/9b5ca9df6642173e20058853031b8d88